# How to calculate centre of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, coordinate-systems, geometry

How do I find the centre of mass with given coordinates?

For example if we have four objects with mass $m$ at coordinates of a square $(0,0,0),(0,0,a),(0,a,0),(0,a,a)$ or another example with eight objects with mass $m$ at coordinates of a cube $(2a,a,a),(2a,-a,a), (2a,a,-a),(2a,-a,-a)$ and $(4a,a,a), (4a,-a, a), (4a,a,-a), (4a,-a,-a)$?

Is there a general way of finding the centre of mass?

Comment: The things you've written down are neither squares nor cubes. Also, the "general way" is pretty much what's written in the *definition* of center of mass, so I don't know what you want.

Comment: anyway, does this answer your question http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#A_system_of_particles? If so, great. If not, please try to clarify your question.

Comment: I understand the formula, i just dont understand how to compute the center of mass if i have specific coordinates like the ones in the examples

Comment: Do you understand how to do a centre of mass calculation for masses all on a straight line, such as masses arranged on a beam on a pivot? if not, begin there. if you do, is it the 3D vectors bit that's difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\vec{X}_{cm} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_i m_i \vec{x}_i$$

where $m_i$ is your mass of particle $i$, $\vec{x}_i$ is the position of particle i, and $M$ is your total mass.

Comment: but how do i do this for given coordinates?

Comment: Plug it into the formula.

Comment: How do I do that? I havent worked alot with coordinates

Comment: What do you know? Are you familiar with vectors? Are you familiar with the symbols in the formula? It's hard to know what you're having trouble with if we don't know where you're starting.

Comment: see  the comments

Comment: Which comments in particular. Calculating the center of mass for a discrete set of masses is a direct application of the formula. You plug it in. So what do you not understand about how to plug it in?

Comment: how do i plug it in? these are coordinates, so i cant just fill those in

Comment: @Stan_Allen, Maybe this will help: the $\vec x_i$ means *the position vector* of each of the four points you have. Your four coordinates all describe the *position vector* to the particular point. So, because of the $\sum_i$ sign, you must, for each point, multiply the vector with the mass and then add all that together. It is a simple vector addition formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a comment on Dargscisyhp's post - please don't upvote this.

The equation Dargscisyhp has given you is a vector equation i.e. the $\vec{x}_i$s are vectors. You do the calculation by adding vectors. If you're uncomfortable with this then you can find the $(x_c, y_c, z_c)$ coordinates for the centre of mass by using three separate equations:

$$\begin{align}
x_c &= \frac{1}{M} \sum_i m_i x_i \\
y_c &= \frac{1}{M} \sum_i m_i y_i \\
z_c &= \frac{1}{M} \sum_i m_i z_i
\end{align}$$

Take the first example you give of four equal masses $m$ at $(0,0,0),(0,0,a),(0,a,0)$ and $(0,a,a)$. The four $x$ coordinates are all zero, so we have:

$$ x_c = \frac{1}{m+m+m+m}\left( m\times 0 + m\times 0 + m\times 0 + m\times 0\right) = 0 $$

The four $y$ coordinates are $0, 0, a$ and $a$, so we have:

$$ y_c = \frac{1}{m+m+m+m}\left( m\times 0 + m\times 0 + m\times a + m\times a\right) = \frac{a}{2} $$

And finally the four $z$ coordinates are $0, a, 0$ and $a$, giving us:

$$ z_c = \frac{1}{m+m+m+m}\left( m\times 0 + m\times a + m\times 0 + m\times a\right) = \frac{a}{2} $$

So the centre of mass is at $(0, \tfrac{a}{2}, \tfrac{a}{2})$.

You do exactly the same for the cube. There are just more terms to add up.

This procedure is actually exactly the same as Dargscisyhp describes. All I've done is split the vector addition up to make it three separate equations.